# Why can't i pass an object from my mapped state as a parameter in my react route link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So i'm having trouble passing a value from an object in my mapped state as a parameter. I looked around and this seems to be working for everyone else i can find.

I have also tried to add it as a state or by including it as a query after the pathname

```
Shoppinglist.map(Order =>
                    <tr key={Order.orderId}>
                        <td>{Order.date}</td>
                        <td>{Order.title}</td>
                        <td>{Order.price}</td>
                        <td>{Order.supplier}</td>
                        <td>
                           <Link to={'/CreateOrder/${Order.orderId}'}>
                            New Order</Link>
                        </td>                   
                    </tr>
                )
```

And my route looks like this:

```
<Route path='/CreateOrder/:orderId?' component={CreateOrder} />
```

The path just turns out like this.
`Url:"/CreateOrder/${Order.orderId}`
instead of showing the actual ID after `/CreateOrder/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Template strings use the back-tick character

You are trying to generate the url using the [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) methods from javascript, but **currently use the wrong character** to create it.

> Template literals are enclosed by the **back-tick** ` (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes

To solve your problem, replace

```
<Link to={'/CreateOrder/${Order.orderId}'}>
                            New Order</Link>
```

by

```
<Link to={`/CreateOrder/${Order.orderId}`}>
                            New Order</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use template string here 
replace

```
 <Link to={'/CreateOrder/${Order.orderId}'}>
```

with

```
 <Link to={`/CreateOrder/${Order.orderId}`}> // note backticks
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it was a big help

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything right just use this ` instead of this '

replace this

`<Link to={'/CreateOrder/${Order.orderId}'}>`

with

```
 <Link to={`/CreateOrder/${Order.orderId}`}>
```

For reference of what is template literals

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD52VbXafqU